# Spring Webflux deserialize json with and without unwrapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, jackson-databind

I'm consuming REST services with Spring Webflux using bean deserialization via Jackson, i.e. ObjectMapper.
Some requests need the response object to be unwrapped, some not.

I'm well aware that I can achieve unwrapping wit a bean like

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder unwrappingJacksonBuilder() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.featuresToEnable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
    return builder;
}
```

but this causes all response objects to be unwrapped.

I have tried to use `@JsonDeserialize(MyUnwrappingDeserializer.class)` for the objects which need unwrapping, but I assume there's a much simpler way to do this.

Second idea was to use 2 different ObjectMapper-Beans, one unwrapping and the other one not, but I am missing the link how to configure the respective WebClients with the different ObjectMappers.

Has anyone a hint for this problem?